# Mac OS X Linker

Tags: c++, qt, linker, undefined, symbols

So I tried to compile one of those altcoins (Bitcoin copies) QT client for Mac OS X Mavericks, and after some time lost putting everything together (boost, db48, miniupnpc, qt 4.8.5 and qt creator 2.5.2) I could compile the code but when arriving in the stage of linking the files, I get an "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" error. Here is the whole output :

```
g++ -headerpad_max_install_names -fstack-protector -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -o Bosscoin-Qt.app/Contents/MacOS/Bosscoin-Qt build/macdockiconhandler.o build/bitcoin.o build/bitcoingui.o build/transactiontablemodel.o build/addresstablemodel.o build/optionsdialog.o build/sendcoinsdialog.o build/addressbookpage.o build/signverifymessagedialog.o build/aboutdialog.o build/editaddressdialog.o build/bitcoinaddressvalidator.o build/version.o build/sync.o build/util.o build/netbase.o build/key.o build/script.o build/main.o build/init.o build/net.o build/irc.o build/checkpoints.o build/addrman.o build/db.o build/walletdb.o build/json_spirit_writer.o build/json_spirit_value.o build/json_spirit_reader.o build/clientmodel.o build/guiutil.o build/transactionrecord.o build/optionsmodel.o build/monitoreddatamapper.o build/transactiondesc.o build/transactiondescdialog.o build/bitcoinstrings.o build/bitcoinamountfield.o build/wallet.o build/keystore.o build/transactionfilterproxy.o build/transactionview.o build/walletmodel.o build/bitcoinrpc.o build/rpcdump.o build/rpcnet.o build/rpcrawtransaction.o build/overviewpage.o build/csvmodelwriter.o build/crypter.o build/sendcoinsentry.o build/qvalidatedlineedit.o build/bitcoinunits.o build/qvaluecombobox.o build/askpassphrasedialog.o build/protocol.o build/notificator.o build/qtipcserver.o build/rpcconsole.o build/scrypt.o build/miningpage.o build/noui.o build/moc_bitcoingui.o build/moc_transactiontablemodel.o build/moc_addresstablemodel.o build/moc_optionsdialog.o build/moc_sendcoinsdialog.o build/moc_addressbookpage.o build/moc_signverifymessagedialog.o build/moc_aboutdialog.o build/moc_editaddressdialog.o build/moc_bitcoinaddressvalidator.o build/moc_clientmodel.o build/moc_guiutil.o build/moc_optionsmodel.o build/moc_monitoreddatamapper.o build/moc_transactiondesc.o build/moc_transactiondescdialog.o build/moc_bitcoinamountfield.o build/moc_transactionfilterproxy.o build/moc_transactionview.o build/moc_walletmodel.o build/moc_overviewpage.o build/moc_csvmodelwriter.o build/moc_sendcoinsentry.o build/moc_qvalidatedlineedit.o build/moc_qvaluecombobox.o build/moc_askpassphrasedialog.o build/moc_notificator.o build/moc_miningpage.o build/moc_rpcconsole.o build/moc_macdockiconhandler.o build/qrc_bitcoin.o
-F/Library/Frameworks -L/Library/Frameworks -lminiupnpc -framework Foundation -framework ApplicationServices -framework AppKit -L/opt/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib/db48 -lssl -lcrypto -ldb_cxx-4.8 -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_program_options-mt -lboost_thread-mt -framework QtGui -framework QtCore 
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "boost::program_options::to_internal(std::string const&)", referenced from:
 boost::program_options::detail::basic_config_file_iterator<char>::getline(std::string&) in util.o
 "boost::program_options::detail::common_config_file_iterator::common_config_file_iterator(std::set<std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, bool)", referenced from:
 boost::program_options::detail::basic_config_file_iterator<char>::basic_config_file_iterator(std::istream&, std::set<std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, bool) in util.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
 make: *** [Bosscoin-Qt.app/Contents/MacOS/Bosscoin-Qt] Error 1
 make: Leaving directory `/Users/kriegalex/dev/bosscoin/bosscoin-qt-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_5_in_PATH__System__Release'
 13:30:58: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
 Error while building/deploying project bosscoin-qt (target: Desktop)
```

I really tried to go through a lot of threads talking of boost and linking problems and I tried to compile with g++ or clang++ as suggested in the most popular thread, but nothing seems to work.

I would really appreciate some help. I think if someone has already compiled Mac OS QT clients, it should be fairly clear what's wrong.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution and now it's working, but I'm not sure which one solved the problem :

- Get Qt from Homebrew (brew install qt), not from Macports or the official website
- Ask macports to install boost and other dependencies with tag +universal

  `sudo port install boost +universal`
- Then I just used qmake and make to compile (as described everywhere)

I think it's the second solution that solved it because it compiled the 64 bits libraries.

Thank you bibi to pointing me to the 32/64 bit problem :)

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are building for 64bit but some libs are 32bit
try to force it in the .pro

```
CONFIG+=x86
```

Comment: Well thanks to your comment I saw that Qt Creator only allows me to choose between GCC 64 bit or Clang 64 bit, so the CONFIG+=x86_64 is automatically added to the qmake command. Maybe I have to uninstall QT4 and reinstall it with some options to activate 32 bit support... I'll try to qmake in 32 bit without Qt Creator and if this doesn't work I'll try to reinstall Qt to allow the 32 bits compiler to be active

Comment: So I added the CONFIG+=x86 in my .pro and in my qmake command and I tried to run qmake outside of Qt Creator, but something is still strange :

clang++ -c -pipe -fstack-protector -O2 -arch x86_64 -arch i386

Why is there two "-arch" definitions ? I don't see where the first comes from ...

Comment: probably by default qt enables the 64bit try to remove it with 
    CONFIG-=x86_64